# UNION ALL -> ORDER BY not working as expected ...?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL-Statement:

```
  (SELECT animation_id,
          animation_name,
          animation_group
   FROM animations
   WHERE animation_id = '45')
UNION ALL
  (SELECT animation_id,
          animation_name,
          animation_group
   FROM animations
   WHERE animation_id <> '45'
     AND active = TRUE
   ORDER BY animation_group,
            animation_name)
```

The table looks like this:

[image: Table]

The sorting is not OK. I wanted that the data is being sorted by the column "animation_group", but the result is sorted after "animation_id" I think.
Look at the screenshot, which shows the output:

[image: Sorting]

If it is relevant: It is MySQL. The Statement is beeing called through PHP.

Is the SQL-Statement correct?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
The base of my request or lets say the reason why I use the UNION is the following:

The result of the first select should always be the first row.
The result of the second select should be ordered by. Therefore I don't want to order the whole result.

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis so that the `ORDER BY` is honored for the entire result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually add a sort ordering for the selected item:

```
SELECT
  animation_id, 
  animation_name, 
  animation_group,
  CASE WHEN animation_id = '45' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_selected
FROM 
  animations
WHERE 
  animation_id = '45' OR (animation_id <> '45' AND active = true)
ORDER BY 
  is_selected DESC,
  animation_group, 
  animation_name
```

If you still want to keep your `UNION` for some reason:

```
SELECT 
  animation_id, 
  animation_name, 
  animation_group,
  1 AS is_selected
FROM 
  animations
WHERE 
  animation_id = '45'
UNION ALL -- If animation_id is unique, I can't see why you'd need a UNION ALL here, by the way 
SELECT 
  animation_id, 
  animation_name, 
  animation_group,
  0 AS is_selected
FROM 
  animations
WHERE
  animation_id <> '45' AND 
  active = true
ORDER BY
  is_selected DESC,
  animation_group, 
  animation_name
```

Also, assuming `animation_id` is a unique integer, 1) you don't need UNION ALL, as each row selected will be unique anyway, and 2) you don't need the quotes around the values, i.e. just `animation_id = 45` will work, rather than `animation_id = '45'`.

Comment: Thank you Matt!!! - It seems to work flawlessly with your "CASE WHEN" solution. I have never used it before.
Would you be so kind to answer me the following:
Do I still need the line "animation_id = '45' OR (animation_id <> '45' AND active = true)" and why?
I think I would only need the active-clause?

Comment: I think only you can answer that—I don't know what your `active` flag represents, or if it could ever not be true for the selected animation, and so on. You'll need to have a think about it and maybe try some experiments.

Comment: Your solution works absolutely fine and bulletproof. I have just replaced all similar UNION's in my project with "CASE WHEN ..." :-) :-) :-)
I will think about the active-flag and test it out.

Comment: The first option seems the best one. Using <> in a where clause tends to be slow, as it almost always disallows using indices. Moreover, you're executing two queries instead of one. About the 1) comment by Matt Gibson, I would say exactly the contrary: UNION can be regarded as a UNION ALL plus duplicate elimination, which is usually costly. So, for me, the question would be "do I need UNION when there are no duplicates and UNION ALL will return the same result?"

Answer (score 3):

*"UNION ALL -> ORDER BY not working as expected"* -- indeed, it's not working as expected, it is working as [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html):

> Use of `ORDER BY` for individual `SELECT` statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because `UNION` by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of `ORDER BY` in this context is typically in conjunction with `LIMIT`, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the `SELECT`, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final `UNION` result. If `ORDER BY` appears without `LIMIT` in a `SELECT`, it is optimized away because it will have no effect anyway.
>
> To use an `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` clause to sort or limit the entire `UNION` result, parenthesize the individual `SELECT` statements and place the `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` after the last one.

Following the documentation advice, your query should be:

```
(
    SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
    FROM animations
    WHERE animation_id = '45'
)
UNION ALL 
(
    SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
    FROM animations
    WHERE animation_id <> '45' and active = true
)
ORDER BY animation_group, animation_name
```

---

More, your query selects the record that have either `animation_id = 45` OR `active = true` and therefore it can be written as:

```
SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
FROM animations
WHERE animation_id = '45' OR active = true
ORDER BY animation_group, animation_name
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no `group by` rather the issue is with `order by`. Second, don't see why you need a `UNION` here. You can change your query to be like below using a `OR` condition probably

```
SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
FROM animations
WHERE animation_id = '45'
OR (animation_id <> '45' and active = true)
ORDER BY animation_group, animation_name;
```

Comment: I'm sorry - you are right. I have corrected the title.
The base of the request is, that the selected value (in this case id=45) would be the first row in the result.

Comment: I personally always have a preference for putting bracket round an `OR` in a `WHERE` clause. Too any times I've just tacked a little `AND` onto the end of the `WHERE` and paid the price of ANDs before ORs operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
  FROM animations
  WHERE animation_id = '45'
UNION ALL 
  SELECT animation_id, animation_name, animation_group
  FROM animations
  WHERE animation_id <> '45' and active = true
) as tmp_table
ORDER BY animation_group, animation_name;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I will update the request.
The base of the request is, that the selected value (in this case id=45) would be the first row in the result.
With your statement all results will be ordered and the selected value is not in the first row anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't enclose the order by inside parentheses. 
Doing so, performs the order by for the second query only and not the result. Moreover, UNION is free to reorder results. An order by after one or more UNION applies to the result of the unions, but only if you don't change its scope using parentheses. 
Your query will work if you remove parentheses.